# make a plot showing the max position of each column

Tags: r

1- I want to make a data frame or matrix which each column is different from another one (at least 50% different)

what i do is for example

```
M <- data.frame(matrix(runif(5),10000,50))
```

Then I want to find the position and the values of max values of each column from M

I can find the position of the max value of each column by using

```
indexmax <- apply(M, MARGIN = 2, function(x) which(x == max(x), arr.ind = TRUE))
```

my main question is now how to make a plot which shows the position of these indices

In X axis ranging from 1 to number of columns 
IN Y axis ranging from 1 to number of rows

then highlight whether the max value was in bottom rows or top rows of the data

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Pascal in fact, i have been trying too much but no results.

Comment: It is always better to show some effort, to increase the chance to get an answer and to reduce the risk to see the post to be closed.

Comment: @Pascal now i solved the first and second one , I only need to plot it, I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

M <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100), ncol=10))
res <- sapply(M, function(x) x>=max(x))
where <- sapply(M, function(x) which.max(x)>length(x)/2)
where <- data.frame('x'=1:ncol(M), 'y'=0, 'label'=factor(where, labels=c("sup", "inf")))

ggplot(data=melt(t(res))) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value))+
  scale_y_reverse() + xlab("columns") + ylab("rows") +
  geom_text(data=where, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="is maximum?"))
```

The script creates a random matrix, then creates a logical copy of M telling if each value is a maximum or not. Than it creates a 'where' vector telling if each column has the maximum in the top rows or not, and transforms this vector into a named 2-level factor. Eventually, it uses ggplot and reshape to plot both information with a 'tile' visualisation.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Given that you have a really big matrix (30000*2000), plotting the position of the maxima would be totally useless. Instead, we can plot the information of wether it is in the upper or lower part of the matrix:

```
M <- data.frame(matrix(runif(20000), ncol=2000))
res <- sapply(M, function(x) x>=max(x))
where <- sapply(M, function(x) which.max(x)>length(x)/2)
image(as.matrix(cbind(!where, where)))
```

[image]

The red color indicated where the maximum is in each column. *Still, be careful with the which.max function in case your data has several maxima per column this graphical representation could be misleading.*

Comment: thanks for your message but there are already two problems with your commands line  one is just print the first "where" you can see it prints the FALSE values and not true values . The second problem is when I run the second "where" command and I get error like Error in factor(where, labels = c("sup", "inf")) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 1

Comment: the error comes from the fact that the data frame you created is the repetition of 50 times the same column and that each column has repeated values of the same maximum. So that's why it prints only the FALSE values: which.max takes the first maximum found and says "there it is!", so always on the bottom or the top. That's also why the second where line gives an error (there is no TRUE value!). Try the code on real data, it won't give error i presume

Comment: thanks for your message! so, can you make a matrix that is different ? does not have max values the same? is it possible that plot it with points connected by a line ? my real data is huge something like 30000 rows and 2000 columns , so the most efficient way is the best !

Comment: in my code the M assignment line gives an example of random data. However, if your data is so big, i'm afraid you won't be able to see anything on a plot, unless you have a screen the size of a building

Comment: do you think it is not better then I only plot the indexes numbers instead like "plot(1:length(indexmax), indexmax, type="l") " ?

Comment: nothing is 'better', it depends of what you want to do next with this information! but yes you can try stripchart, boxplot, density plot, ... for instance if you want to test if there is a pattern in the position of your maxima are spatially correlated you can try plotting an ACF: acf(indexmax)

Comment: I only need to show whether the max value is in the top of the data or bottom. however, the data is huge and that is make it so difficult to do !

Comment: thanks , can you also please modify the x-axis and y-axis? what are these ? so that I have a clue how to track the results

Comment: x: the 2000 columns. y: the 2 zones (top or bottom). if you want the column numbers you can add these two arguments in the image function: x=1:2000, y=-1:1

Comment: thank you, although this is not the exact solution (the problem is due to the dimension of my data). I accept your solution because you did already a lot. Thanks again agenis :-)